# Is there a way for two different Docker overlay networks to communicate?

Tags: docker, docker-network

As an example take container 1 (`c1`) and container 2 (`c2`) on the overlay networks `172.0.0.0/24` and `192.0.0.0/24` respectively.

Is there a way to customize the two overlay networks - perhaps on creation with some custom settings - to allow communication from `c1` to `c2` and vice-versa?

So far, I've tried having a vyos router container (`2stacks/vyos` image) with the routing rules configured within it. In this instance, I would have to also set routing rules within the `c1` and/or `c2` to allow the following path:

`c1` >>> `vyos-container` >> `c2`.

However, this is not scalable as it depends heavily on the specific constraints of the Docker images used for `c1` and `c2` and involves entering the container to make changes.

I've also tried to set the `--gateway` IP when running `docker network create` to point to an IP that I will eventually assign to the vyos router to achieve the path mentioned above. However, Docker errors when I try to assign the `--gateway` IP address to any subsequent containers.

Is there a less manual and more general/reusable way to achieve this using default Docker commands?

I'm coming from a software background with more limited networking knowledge so I may be missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try **docker-compose**? and use network for specific only container what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I’m not sure I follow. Can you expand on what you mean? If you’re suggesting simply putting both containers on the same network then that’s not the desired behaviour unfortunately. Also unsure how Docker Compose is significant here as this issue isn’t about orchestration.